# Perl crypt() acting weird

Tags: perl, cgi, crypt

I'm using the function below to create a hash for a one-time download link (Originally from perlmonks). The weird thing is I always get the same hash result.

I've been RTFMing. I made sure that the crypt() function gets the last 8 characters of $exp, and also verified the $exp indeed changes. I've also tried manually feeding the crypt() function with random values, only those worked out fine and the hash result changed.

What am I missing here?

```
use strict;
use CGI;

sub chash {
my $exp = $_;
my $key = 'abcd1234'; //not actual key
my $hash = crypt(substr($exp,-8,8),$key);
$hash = substr($hash, 2);
$hash =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g; $hash = uc($hash);

return $hash;
}

my $exp = time() + 60;    
my $hash = chash($exp);
my $download_url="http://script.pl?$exp-$hash";
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to pull the first item off `@_` instead of trying to read `$_` in your sub.

```
my $exp = shift;
```

or

```
my ($exp) = @_;
```

or

```
my $exp = $_[0];
```

From [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> Any arguments passed in show up in the array `@_` . Therefore, if you called a function with two arguments, those would be stored in `$_[0]` and `$_[1]` . The array `@_` is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters to a `sub` will be passed in `@_` not in `$_`.

```
use strict;
use warnings ;
use CGI;

sub chash {
  my ( $exp ) = @_;
  my $key = 'abcd1234'; # not actual key
  my $hash = crypt(substr($exp,-8,8),$key);
  $hash = substr($hash, 2);
  $hash =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g;
  $hash = uc($hash);

  return $hash;
}

my $exp = time() + 60;    
my $hash = chash($exp);
my $download_url="http://script.pl?$exp-$hash";
```

Using `use warnings;` would have hinted you to this mistake.